# How to slice pandas DataFrame so pylance doesn't give error about returned type being NDFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, python-typing, pylance

I have big pandas `DataFrame` which I need to slice.

I noticed that after slicing VSCode assumes `NDFrame` instead of `DataFrame`.

I'm using only 2-dimensional dataframes, so having `NDFrame` is confusing for me. I prefer to use just `DataFrame`. Python code works as expected, this seems to be an issue in `pylance` extension.

How can I receive `DataFrame` after slicing?

Example code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

df1: DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"],
        "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"],
        "C": ["C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"],
        "D": ["D0", "D1", "D2", "D3"],
    },
    index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
)

df2: DataFrame =df1[:2]

print(type(df1))
print(type(df2))
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

VSCode `pylance` type checking error:

[image]

Comment: `df2` will be a slice of `df1`, not a brand new dataframe. `df2 = df1[:2].copy()` should suppress the warning (but I'm not sure if it is the desired logic)

Comment: @Marat `df2 = df1[:2].copy()` isn't suppressing the warning, it seems to be an issue only on editor side, not python. After analyzing it I came to a conclusion that I won't need to use `copy()` in my code, but thank you for your suggestion, I learned more about the internals of pandas by reading how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to correct this you can use `iloc`:

```py
    n = 2
    # iloc (note the difference for Series [:n] and DataFrame [:n,:]):
    df2: DataFrame = df.iloc[:n,:] # first n rows
    df3: DataFrame = df.iloc[-n:,:] # last n rows
```

or simply use `head(n)` for get first `n` and `tail(n)` for get last `n` rows:

```py
    n = 2
    df2: DataFrame = df.head(n)
    df3: DataFrame = df.tail(n)
```

in the same way `head(-n)` for drop last `n` row and `tail(-n)` for drop first `n` rows:

```py
    n = 2
    df2: DataFrame = df.head(-n)
    df3: DataFrame = df.tail(-n)
```

to learn more read: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError` when I try to use `df2: DataFrame =df1[:2,:]`. But `df2: DataFrame =df1.iloc[:2,:]` and `df2: DataFrame =df1.head(2)` work ok

Comment: Thx. I have edited